# Nullable object must have a value. C# MVC CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm running into this issue and not sure how to solve it.

**Model**

```
public bool? Rem1SendToEmail1 { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Rem1SendToEmail1.Value)
```

**Controller**

```
smsAccount.Rem1SendToEmail1 = ClientSMSAccountModal.Rem1SendToEmail1.Value;
```

**Error**

> Nullable object must have a value.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

When I try to change the view to

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Rem1SendToEmail1)
```

I get the following error:

> Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` for a nullable `bool` (make the property `bool`, of use `EditorFor()` which will generate a checkbox for the 3 possible states.

Comment: If you leave it nullable, you also need to change the controller code, since calling `.Value` on a nullable type when there is no value will generate that exception.

Comment: @DStanley, That will not bind (you cannot use `CheckBoxFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I used EditorFor and got the same error

Comment: I think I need to change the Model property from bool? to just bool

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Rem1SendToEmail1)` will not generate that error. It will render a dropdownlist with 3 values - 'Not Set', 'True' and 'False'

Comment: @StephenMuecke i changed it to @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Rem2SendToEmail1)  and it's displaying the checkbox, but when I try to submit I still get the initial nullable error

Comment: Do you mean you have now changed the property to `public bool Rem1SendToEmail1 { get; set; }` (not nullable)?

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: Checkbox can be true or false, it is either 1 or 0, nothing in-between. Your model is a nullable bool, but the checkbox control expects true or false, zero or one, but null isn't an accepted value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the property is still the same as in the question. I've only updated the CheckBoxFor to EditorFor

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did not say to use `CheckBoxFor` - I'm saying if you change it to `EditorFor` and leave the field as nullable, then you have to check for a value with `HasValue` _before_ calling `.Value` or you'll still get that exception.

Comment: I've now changed it to EditorFor, that means I need to change the property to public bool Rem1SendToEmail1 { get; set; } ?

Comment: No. If the property is `bool?`, then you MUST use `EditorFor()` which will generate a `<select>`. If its `bool` then you can use either `CheckBoxFor()` or `EditorFor()` and both will generate `<input type="checkbox" .. />`

Comment: @StephenMuecke using bool?  the EditorFor was generating a checkbox. I was still getting the error on submit however. I've now changed the property to bool and the error is resolved.

Comment: That is simply not possible unless you have created an `EditorTemplate` for `bool?` (and generating a checkbox for a `bool?` makes no sense since a `bool?` has 3 possible states where as a checkbox has only 2)

Comment: I'm using a standard admin theme which has the following Boolean Editor Template:   
@model bool?

@Html.CheckBox("", Model.GetValueOrDefault())

Comment: Then get rid of that (its simply wrong and makes no sense)

Comment: After removing that, it gave me an error on another part of the system, so going to leave it there for now and focus on the saving issue I'm having. I have the checkbox displaying and it is submitting without the nullable error now. Just need to debug the rest of it to get the values saving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162772/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-orion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the help provided in comments I changed my code as follows and nullbale error was resolved:

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Rem1SendToEmail1)
```

**Model**

```
public bool Rem1SendToEmail1 { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
smsAccount.Rem1SendToEmail1 = ClientSMSAccountModal.Rem1SendToEmail1;
```